# Constexpr conditions for constructor

Tags: c++, oop, c++14, constexpr

On [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) site, it is specified that:

> "A constexpr function must satisfy the following requirements:
>
> [...]
>
> there exists at least one set of argument values such that an invocation of the function could be an evaluated subexpression of a core constant expression (**for constructors, use in a constant initializer is sufficient**) (since C++14). No diagnostic is required for a violation of this bullet."

What is the meaning of the bolded statement?

Comment: The linked site is slightly confusing, as it makes it look like a constructor might be a constexpr function. The term constexpr function never applies to constructors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the [linked defect report](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1911)

```
struct X {
    std::unique_ptr<int> p;
    constexpr X() { }
};
```

Before C++14, this would be ill-formed due to [[dcl.constexpr]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.constexpr#5)

> For a constexpr constructor, if no argument values exist such that after function invocation substitution, every constructor call and full-expression in the mem-initializers would be a constant expression (including conversions), the program is ill-formed; no diagnostic required.

Which mandates that there exists some argument (in this case, only the empty set) that can create a constant expression for the invocation of `X::X`, as in

```
constexpr X x;  // must be valid before C++14
```

Since `std::unique_ptr` isn't a literal type, it has a non-trivial destructor, this is impossible. Yet the defect report proposed that `constexpr` constructors should still be well-formed in such cases due to this kind of use case

```
X x;  // not constexpr, but initialization should be constant
```

Hence the rewording

> For a constexpr function or constexpr constructor that is neither defaulted nor a template, if no argument values exist such that an invocation of the function or constructor could be an evaluated subexpression of a core constant expression, or, **for a constructor, a constant initializer for some object** , the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

Translated, it means: a `constexpr` constructor is well-formed as long as it is a `constexpr` function, and its member initializations are also `constexpr` functions, even if the type itself can never be `constexpr`.

Comment: Just to make sure I understood. Because the invocation of a constructor may result in an expression that is not `constexpr`, it is enough for a constructor to just be a `constexpr` function in order to be regarded as `constexpr`? Thank you.

Comment: Not in order for it to be regarded as `constexpr`, but to make the program well-formed. Note the last sentence says *"ill-formed, no diagnostic required"*, it means that your program may explode into pieces without warning. PS mark accepted if you accept

Comment: I thought that if the program is well-formed, the `constexpr` "specifier" associated with the constructor is regarded as "correct".

Comment: @user42768 If no arguments exist such that a non-constructor function can return a constant expression, the compiler is likely going to compile just fine, but your program is ill-formed. The extra wording on the constructor is saying when exactly it's ill-formed

Comment: In that situation I refer to the `constexpr` specifier as being "incorrect". Anyway, it is just a matter of referring to the same thing, I think.

Comment: The reason for having a constexpr constructor of a non-literal type would be to initialize non-constexpr objects at compile-time, correct? Are there any other uses?

Comment: Your first (shortened version of the) quote is inapplicable, since it applies only to constexpr functions, not to constexpr constructors.